# Does .spawn() multiprocessing copy nothing over from its parent?

Tags: python, concurrency, operating-system, multiprocessing

Running python 3.8 with MacOSX. My understanding of spawn multiprocessing is that it creates a new process, imports the parent module, and then runs whatever function it was called with. Spawn doesn't actually copy any of the working memory of the parent function. Is that true?

Comment: That is more or less true.  However: Prior to executing the function, the address space is initialized by relaunching a new Python interpreter that re-reads the source and executes *everything* at global scope, not just import statements, and then the function is called. The only difference is that in the new process  `__name__` is no longer '\_\_main__'.

Comment: To expand on that... once the `"__main__"` file is executed (with `__name__ = "__mp_main__"`) and some namespace cleanup is done, the `Process` object from the parent process is pickled, and sent to the child where its `run` method gets called. This is how the arguments are passed (they are attributes of the process object). The `target` of the process is typically a function, and pickling functions doesn't actually send the code object itself, rather just the fully qualified namespace path to find / import the appropriate function.

Comment: When we subclass Process, like class Producer(mp.Process), and we include variables in the __init__ clause of Producer, then where in memory are these objects? I assume they are created in the parent process (before the spawn) and just passed to the .run method?